# Delegates in Threads and Anonymous methods - Update controls in new Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, delegates

I was using multithreading in my window form. Following is my class. 
I have a label control in my designer and under the newly created thread I am updating it's text property.

Following is the case when I encapsulated the function "UpdateLabel" in a delegate "Del".
and it works fine.

```
public partial class DynamicType : Form
    {
        delegate void Del(String x);

        public DynamicType()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DynamicType_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(StartThread));
            t.Start();
        }

        private void StartThread()
        {
            this.Invoke(new Del(UpdateLabel), new object[] { "Hi" });
        }

        private void UpdateLabel(String str)
        {
            label1.Text = str;
        }
    }
```

I have a another case called Anonymous Methods. Upon implementing the Anonymous methods
in the following methods. Following are the definitions.

```
private void StartThread()
        {
            UpdateLabel("Hi");
        }



private void UpdateLabel(String str)
        {
            Del Label = delegate(String k)
             {
                 label1.Text = k;

             };
            Label("hi");
        }
```

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

My query is in the previous case I was using the delegates and it worked fine and in case of anonymous methods I removed the extra functions by directly instantiating the delegates and tried to update the label control text property and it gave the crash as mentioned above. Reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you are calling the label update in the UI thread (via `Form.Invoke`). This is correct and works:

```
this.Invoke(new Del(UpdateLabel), new object[] { "Hi" });
```

In the second example, you are creating a delegate in the background thread **and starting that delegate in the background thread**. That doesn't work, because the background thread is not allowed to update the UI:

```
Del Label = delegate(String k) { label1.Text = k; }; 
Label("hi");   // runs in the same thread
```

To solve this, you have to use `this.Invoke` to execute the delegate in the UI thread:

```
Del Label = delegate(String k) { label1.Text = k; }; 
this.Invoke(Label, new object[] {"hi"});   // runs in the UI thread
```